# Strings not referenced by dicts?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, reference, cpython

Look at this Python code:

```
from gc import get_referrers as refs
x = 'x'
d = {x:x}
print(d in refs(x))
```

It prints False. That's weird by itself, but becomes much weirder when you consider the following:

- If x is a number (int, float, complex, Fraction, Decimal) instead of a string, it still prints False. For bytes and bytearray, too. But for every other type (hashable if used as key, like tuple or frozenset - but many other, if used as value only), it prints True.
- If d is any other container (set, list, tuple...) containing x, it prints True. Only for a dict, it prints False. Also, it doesn't matter if x is a key or a value, or as above, both.

I thought in Python every object is a reference (as opposed to Java, which has primitive types, or Ruby, which value-types small ints), but now it seems str and int are kinda primitive types, that aren't referenced. But on the other hand, why only in dicts??

I also know that ints from -5 to 256 are cached in CPython (and small strings can be interned), so it makes sense not to refcount them, since they will never be deleted anyway, but this works for any integers (and long strings) I've tried, much larger than that range.

Does anybody know what's going on here?

--- UPDATE ---

Curiouser and curiouser... it seems datetime.{datetime, date, time} classes have the same "unreferenced" behaviour. Now, I know *one* thing that those, AnyStr and Number have in common: their hashes are randomized with a per-session salt. But this doesn't make *any* sense, since the behaviour is observed even when these are merely *values* in dicts, not keys. And values are not hashed. Or are they?

Comment: Interesting, the reference count (`sys.getrefcount`) does increase by 2 after assigning the dictionary.  but the `get_referrers` even returns False if the key and value are different (and one is x), so it does not appear to be a protection against circular references.

Comment: Yes, that was one of my hypotheses, but as you said, it doesn't hold since x doesn't have to be both key and value. And other containers (lists) can have circular references, they don't exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: BTW, the symptoms are similar in Python 2.7 and 3.4, the reference counts are sightly different total numbers, which is to be expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `gcmodule.c`:

> Certain types of container cannot participate in a reference cycle, and
>   so do not need to be tracked by the garbage collector. Untracking these
>   objects reduces the cost of garbage collections. However, determining
>   which objects may be untracked is not free, and the costs must be
>   weighed against the benefits for garbage collection.
>
> ...
>
> *Dictionaries containing only immutable objects* also do not need to be
>   tracked. Dictionaries are untracked when created. If a tracked item is
>   inserted into a dictionary (either as a key or value), the dictionary
>   becomes tracked. During a full garbage collection (all generations),
>   the collector will untrack any dictionaries whose contents are not
>   tracked.

Basically, since object in Python are reference-counting, the goal of garbage collector is to break reference cycles, other unreferenced objects are destroyed when last reference goes away. For optimization, garbage collector doesn't keep track of certain objects which simply can never participate in reference cycles.

So, strings *are* referenced. However, the garbage collector is not interested in these dictionaries at all and therefore `gc.get_referrers()` doesn't list them.

Comment: Just found that in the source as well, you beat me to it.  Interestingly, if the value is immutable (the key can't be) the value appears in `get_referrers()`, but the key never does, which might contradict the quote (although it says the *dictionary* becomes tracked, not the key).

Comment: Scrub that last comment.  The key is not tracked if it is (I'm guessing) cached.   Changing `x` to "Slartibartfast" and the value to `[1,2,3,4]`, gives both key and value as tracking in `gc.get_referrers()`.  Clearly there is some magic here.

Comment: It seems grepping the source is really good for the soul, as a certain Larry Wall used to say. :-) Thanks. But I still can't see why only dicts and not sets... it's as if sets are really second-class objects in Python. :-)